# How to read datagrid checkbox status when populating the datagrid with an itemsource in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, itemsource

I have a DataGrid that i am populating using its items source and setting it equal to a DataTable's default view like this:

```
exampleDataGrid.ItemsSource = exampleDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Here is the XAML for the datagrid im using:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="exampleDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="261" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" Margin="2,0,-2,0" GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="select">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox x:Name="CK" Content="{Binding Data}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PARTTYPE}" Width="Auto"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

It will look something like this (I removed the grid and header):

[image]

The problem I'm having is i can't check if the check box is checked or not with items source in use.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Some would help here and can you let us know how are you checking whether the checkbox is checked?

Comment: put the code with which you checking is checked condition